# Position:fixed column in fluid css

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm trying to build a basic html fluid template (12 columns) where I'd like the first column to be in `position:fixed`. This first column would host the navigation on desktop screen. When viewing the page with a mobile, this column needs to be the first in the flow.

https://jsfiddle.net/b4aqu9d7/

I know that the problem comes from the `position:fixed` in the css as it comes out of the flow. I have tried to push the fluid part with margins but I have not managed to have a perfectly balanced page with one fixed column and the rest in fluid.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to solve the issue with margins.

Instead of using nested sections, I'm using only one.

Solution is here:

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/c9evuzqb/1/>
```